# How to snap full screen applications left / right?

Tags: windows-11

I've just got a 42:9 ultrawide and Im struggling with getting full screen/borderless windows to behave as I want. Does anyone know how to snap windows left / right for full screen apps? Windows + left/right sadly doesnt seem to work when the app is full screen or a borderless window.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows 11:

- Open the app in full screen.
- Press Windows Button + Z
- Press the number(s) corresponding to the snap location.

This works fine for me.

Comment: Not that it works, but very useful shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

What type of graphics card you are using? Try to key in CTRL+ALT+F11 for panel fitting.

Comment: I've got a 3080Ti FE the command doesnt seem to do anything sadly

Answer (score 0):

One way to consequently choose where to fit windows would be the Windows PowerToys. In earlier versions you needed to install it from the [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys) page, now on windows 11 you can get it directly from the Microsoft Store. With it you can draw areas on the screen where you want windows to snap in.

Comment: I've got power toys, its fantastic but only lets you snap applications that are draggable, so full screen and bordless windowed apps such as video games tend not to work :(

Comment: Oh, well, then I’m sorry, I never had problems with windows not working as expected

Answer (score 0):

I've found this one that ACTUALLY works for YouTube (unlike the other links suggested in this thread, none of which worked for me: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/windowed-floating-youtube/gibipneadnbflmkebnmcbgjdkngkbklb

Doesn't work on all sites, better than nothing.
For sites that it doesn't work with, what I do is I hide the bookmarks bar. Have not found a shortcut or way to hide the address bar however so far.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1217895)